# Giving Feedback Using Apptentive SDK for Android

Tags: android

Hi I am using Apptentive Sdk for giving feedback so while clicking on the button i wrote,

```
          Apptentive.showMessageCenter(FeedbackActivity.this);
```

By using this code i got the feedback message popup and when i send the message it shows the list of messages that is been sent to message center, Now when i again click on the button i again want to display popup but message center messages are displayed so can anyone please help me out as i dont want to display the message center messages, I am currently using Andorid Studio for Development. I even reffered this linkapptentive.com/docs/android/integration/ but did'nt found anything.